# convert combobox.selectedItem to int32 c#

Tags: c#

My conversion code is as follows:

```
para = Int32.Parse(cmbCompany.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

The data binding code for my combo-box is as so:

```
string query = "select CompanyID as ID, CompanyName as Name from tblCompany";
comb.ValueMember = "ID";
comb.DisplayMember = "Name";
comb.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

When I run the above code, I get a conversion error:

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: <irony>nice formatting!</irony>

Comment: Instead of `selecteditem` try `selectedvalue`

Comment: Break into the code and see what value it actually holds.  Incidentally if it does hold an integer you don't need to convert it to a string and then parse it to an integer - just unbox it.  (int)cmbCompany.SelectedValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem have been solved.i do the following

```
 Int32.Parse(((DataRowView)cmbCompany.SelectedItem).Row["ID"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use comboBox1.SelectedValue

```
 Int32.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

You can use [**Int32.TryParse**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) if you expect empty value for combo

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out number);
if (result)
{
     //Your code
}
```

Comment: instead of `Int32.Parse` `Int32.TryParse` will be better here. Data can be empty string. [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Normally id is not empty but could be so Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another technique is to use [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx)

```
Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
```